# Javascript/Typescript partition function from ramda implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

Hell,
I'm working for implementation for R.partition from 'ramda'. without using push!!
only using map, filter, reduce functions.

This is my current implementation :

```
partition = <T>(func : (param : T) => boolean, arr : T[]): T[][] => {
return [arr.filter((element : T) => func(element)), arr.filter((element : T) => !func(element))];
```

}

example :

```
const func = (x) => x%2 == 0
```

const temp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
console.log(partition(func, tmep)); // => [[2,4,6,8],[1,3,5,7,9]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

A double filtering introduces unnecessary time complexity, 
we don't really need to iterate twice here.

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is our tool here:

```js
const partition = (predicate, list) => list.reduce(
  
  ([left, right], item) => predicate(item) 
    ? [left.concat(item), right]
    : [left, right.concat(item)],
    
  [[], []],
  list
);

//===

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const isOdd = n => n % 2;

const [odds, evens] = partition(isOdd, data);

console.log({ odds, evens });
```